# Adding or merging python dictionaries without loss

Tags: python, dictionary, merge, count, addition

I'm trying to count up ip addresses found in a log file on two servers and then merge the dictionary stats together without loosing elements or counts. I found a partial solution in another stack overflow question but as you can see it drops the `'10.10.0.1':7` pair.

```
>>> a = {'192.168.1.21':23,'127.0.0.1':5,'12.12.12.12':5,'55.55.55.55':10}
>>> b = {'192.168.1.21':27,'10.10.0.1':7,'127.0.0.1':1}
>>> c = {}
>>> for elem in a:
...     c[elem] = b.get(elem, 0) + a[elem]
...
>>> print c
{'55.55.55.55': 10, '12.12.12.12': 5, '127.0.0.1': 6, '192.168.1.21': 50}
```

The counts are being added together but if the key doesn't exist in dict a, it gets dropped.  I'm having trouble figuring out the last bit of logic... perhaps another for elem in b: if a.get(elem, 0) exists: pass else add it to c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code replace `c = {}` with `c = b.copy()`

Answer (score 5):

If you have Python 2.7+, try [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Otherwise try the following:

```
a = {'192.168.1.21':23,'127.0.0.1':5,'12.12.12.12':5,'55.55.55.55':10}
b = {'192.168.1.21':27,'10.10.0.1':7,'127.0.0.1':1}
c = {}
for dictionary in (a,b):
    for k,v in dictionary.iteritems():
        c[k] = c.get(k, 0) + v
```

Comment: I'm on redhat enterprize server 4 server so I have python 2.3.4   : (

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> a = {'192.168.1.21':23,'127.0.0.1':5,'12.12.12.12':5,'55.55.55.55':10}
>>> b = {'192.168.1.21':27,'10.10.0.1':7,'127.0.0.1':1}
>>> Counter(a) + Counter(b)
Counter({'192.168.1.21': 50, '55.55.55.55': 10, '10.10.0.1': 7, '127.0.0.1': 6, '12.12.12.12': 5})
```

Comment: yeah, all you need is `Counter(a) + Counter(b)`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
c = dict((k, a.get(k, 0) + b.get(k, 0)) for k in set(a.keys() + b.keys()))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be a pretty generic answer to your question, if I got it.

```
def merge_sum_dictionaries(*dicts):
    result_dict = {}
    for d in dicts:
        for key, value in d.iteritems():
            result_dict.setdefault(key, 0)
            result_dict[key] += value
    return result_dict



if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = {'192.168.1.21':23,'127.0.0.1':5,'12.12.12.12':5,'55.55.55.55':10}
    b = {'192.168.1.21':27,'10.10.0.1':7,'127.0.0.1':1}

    print merge_sum_dictionaries(a, b)
```

Output:

```
{'55.55.55.55': 10, '10.10.0.1': 7, '12.12.12.12': 5, '127.0.0.1': 6, '192.168.1.21': 50}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for python 2.6 and higher:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def merge_count_dicts(*dicts):
    result = defaultdict(int)
    for d in dicts:
        for k, v in d.items():
            result[k] += v
    return result

def test():
    a = {'192.168.1.21':23,'127.0.0.1':5,'12.12.12.12':5,'55.55.55.55':10}
    b = {'192.168.1.21':27,'10.10.0.1':7,'127.0.0.1':1}
    c = merge_count_dicts(a, b)
    print c

if __name__ == '__main_':
    test()
```

Comment: That's the other way to setdefault() :P